# Laravel Blade Templates not Showing Changes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to PHP and Laravel 5 and working on Windows, Xampp-control. My pages run perfectly almost two days but after that changes made in .blade.php files do not show on browser. Even changing images in public folder have no effect. I re-installed the browser and switched the browser from Chrome to Firefox, but no effect. I found something on internet but couldn't get it. The link is as follows:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40568

Is it due to it or something else is happening? What should I do?

Comment: are there any errors showing when you try to load the page? what is the http status code? and have you checked your xamp logs?

Comment: Are you sure that your views are not simply being cached? What happens when you run `php artisan cache:clear` command?

Comment: Have you tried to clear the /storage/framework/views folder? Which editor you are using (PHPStorm) ?

Comment: Thanks for comments. php artisan cache:clear solved my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are cached that's why this problem is encountering. A simple solution to resolve it is to clear the cache. And you can do it by the following artisan command.

```
php artisan cache:clear
```